# Duplicate append issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the values of a Select2 Menu so that when a button is clicked the name of that value is appended to the page in the form of a tag. Everything works on the first click however when I select another value and the button is clicked, another instance of the previous value is appended as well as the new one. Sorry if this is a dumb question, I'm still learning. Any tips would be appreciated, thank you!!!!

```
$('#e1').click(function() {
    var search_box_name = $('option:selected', this).attr('company_name');
    var search_box_id = $('option:selected', this).attr('id');
    $('#searchbutton').click(function() {
        $('#displaycompanies').append('<span href="#" id='+search_box_id+' class="tags closeme company pull-left">'+search_box_name+'<a href="#" class="btn btn-xs btn-close closeme">X</a></span>');
        $('#form_new_product').append('<input type="hidden" id="'+search_box_id+'" class="closeme" name="company_id[]" value="'+search_box_name+'" />');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use

```
.replaceWith()
```

instead of

```
.append()
```